# Carousel Slider with Filtering

Tags: jquery, filtering, carousel

I'm trying to create a carousel of items, that can be filtered.

I've been trying to use [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) together to accomplish this. But they aren't playing well together. MixItUp hides the items, but Slick seems to unhide them almost immediately. Is there any other library that would work better with Slick for this purpose, or even bxSlider?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.one-time').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 100,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });

$('#product_carousel').mixItUp();

$('#product_carousel').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){

   $('.one-time').slick();
});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the latest version of Slick. I saw this and decided to add a filter method. You can use it like:

```
$('#yourSlider').slickFilter(':even');
```

and use unfilter to return to the original state:

```
$('#yourSlider').slickUnfilter();
```

It accepts jQuery filter syntax, so selectors and comparators both work.

Enjoy!

Comment: @Picard102 How did you end up filtering from the hidden slides when mixitup ends?

Comment: @Tom we ended up using a custom solution, multiple sliders, before Slick added their filtering feature.